# Electromagnetic switch

Tags: voltage, current, switches, electromagnetic, ratings

I have a a electromagnetic level switch with DPDT contacts. Its rating mentioned is 230Vac, 60VA, 1A. My concern is what will be the DC equivalent for this rating. 
I have 24Vdc available from PLC and will current rating change or remain constant if the voltage varies.

Comment: Date sheet link?

Comment: Manufacturer knows that. Try asking him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link from Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/blog/which-switch-who-cares-if-its-ac-or-dc) discusses why there is a difference in the AC and DC rating.  It says:

> When an AC circuit is slowly broken, the arc or spark is extinguished
>   quickly — a desirable condition (AC naturally has "current zeros"
>   twice a cycle.) Conversely, when a DC circuit is slowly broken, the
>   arc can be drawn much longer before it is extinguished. This is an
>   undesirable condition which leads to pitting of switch contacts, which
>   leads to overheating and premature failure of the switch, which can
>   also lead to fire!

[This link from a switch manufacturer](http://www.carlingtech.com/amp-hp-volts) has a rule of thumb for DC ratings.

> For those switches that list an AC voltage rating only, the "DC Rule
>   of Thumb" can be applied for determining the switch's maximum DC
>   current rating. This "rule" states the highest amperage on the switch
>   should perform satisfactorily up to 30 volts DC. For example, a switch
>   which is rated at 10A 250VAC; 15A 125VAC; 3/4HP 125-250VAC, will be
>   likely to perform satisfactorily at 15 amps up to 30 volts DC (VDC).

**From the rule of thumb, you should be able to use your switch for 24V DC at 1A.**

Answer (score 0):

Look it up.  That really should have been obvious.

If the datasheet doesn't give a DC spec, then ask the manufacturer directly or use a different switch.

DC ratings are generally lower due to no zero crossings that help extinguish any arc.  However, how much to derate from the AC values is dependent on the exact construction of the switch, which is something only the manufacturer can know.

There are also regulatory issues.  If the switch isn't rated for your use, then you have more liability if something goes wrong, catches fire, electrocutes someone, etc.